# Display phonemes instead of text [pocketsphinx]

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sphinx4

I have successfully compiled the HelloWorld tutorial of PocketSphinx on my Android device.
[link : http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/]

Now, I need some help to tweak the code of the HelloWorld tutorial so that only the phonemes of the spoken words are displayed on the screen instead of the text.

Comment: It is not possible to archive that with a "tweak". The change will involve serious code modifications.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or if possible could you help me to display the phonemes ? Thank You